# Add weight to a file in Delphi

Tags: delphi

hi was reading the following tutorial: http://www.forumkorner.com/thread-26894.html, the problem is that I find way to how to translate the following code (VB .net):

```
Dim file1 = File.OpenWrite("c:/test.exe")
Dim siza = file1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.[End])
Dim size = Convert.ToInt32("20")
Dim bite As Decimal = size * 1048576
While siza < bite
siza += 1
file1.WriteByte(0)
End While
file1.Close()
End If
```

the question is where do I get the information on how to write bytes to a file ?

Comment: Try the [TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TFileStream) Class.

Comment: Don't translate that code. It is dire. Open a stream in append mode, and write a bunch of zeros. But not one byte at a time. And don't convert `"20"` to integer. That would be `20`. Do you know any pascal? If not, you need to learn it. But why should we write all your code for you?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing/translating service. What have you tried yourself so far to convert the code to Delphi?

Comment: i try add size using this code but do not put that value in the first argument, try 1024 but fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly that the tutoraial that OP refers to was written by some newbie so I wouldn't folow it.

Now if you wanna make program which simply increases the size of certain file there are easier ways to do it. You don't necessarily need to write into the file in order to increase its size.

This code does it without writing a single byte into it:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var FS: TFileStream;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    FS := TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName,fmOpenReadWrite);
    FS.Size := FS.Size *2;
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How? It simply tels the operating system that the size of that specific file needs to be set to specific value (usually used to reserve the disk space before writing large amounts of data into file) and operating system then only changes the information in the file allocation table.

Now biggest advantage of this is that on hard drive this procedure will be done almost instantly regardles of the desired file size while the approach shown in the tutorail OP refered to takes more time for larger files. If the file is on a Flash drive it could take some time due the fact that most flash drives use FAT32 partitions which works a bit different thatn NTFS and therefore require more data to be written into the allocation tables.

EDIT: WARNING! Never and I mean NEVER set the file size smaller that it currently is! If you do so you will cause the los of data which probably won't be posible to repair.

Comment: No problem. I actually use similar approach to create a file in order to fill up the free space of a USB drive when I'm using it to copy an updated AntiVirus software to some computer that I know was infected by virus. This way I prevent virus to potentionaly copy itself to my USB and infect my computer aswell. I even made my program in a way that it can write into this file (simply overwriting existing data) so I can make a backup copy of some important files from infected computer. So far this approach served me well to protect my compiuter even from nastiest viruses some of my friends got.